# Compare more than 2 json file for common properties - Java

Tags: java, json, gson, guava, property-files

I have a list of json property files ( around 20 json property files)

Now, need is to find common properties across these json files.

I have used guava api json file comparison,  it compares 2 json files.

Pls suggest any other efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: You can use _gson_ to iterate on the structures, and identify the equal values.

Comment: yeah i thought of that, but creating a map of Map<"envronment" , "JSON" obj" > and then iterating it , comparing all 20 json files with each other, will that not be too cumbersome ? Did i understand your suggestion correctly?

Comment: I guess, I can't imagine any other way to do it.  Possibly, part of the _gson_ documentation?